# How to gain ebrake slack at the caliper?

Tags: brakes, hyundai, brake-calipers, parking-brake

#### 2006 Hyundai Tiburon

4cyl 2.0L | 
5 speed manual

---

I am trying to reconnect my ebrake cable to my caliper, but there is not enough slack. The one on the other side currently has about 1" more slack than the one shown. The brake is not engaged, and there is slack all along the cable up to the lever. The only place where there is not slack is at the caliper itself. I have tried messing around with the various nuts in the picture to no avail. I do not know what any of them do, as my manual does not really go into details on this particular subject. My question is how do I gain enough slack to set the cable back on the caliper. Is it potentially seized somehow at the end of the line? TIA

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the photo, it looks like the rubber between 'A' and 'B is a concertina? Does it look like the one on the other side is longer than the one on this side? It looks to me like 'A' should be hooked onto the arm on the caliper, with 'B' remaining where it is (and 'C' and 'D' untouched).

It may well be that the inner cable is seized - I'd compare it with the one on the other side to see what looks different.